# How can I get a nested IN clause with a linq2sql query?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I am trying to implement some search functionality within our app and have a situation where a User can select multiple Topics from a list and we want to return all activities that match at least one of the selected Topics. Each Activity can have 0-to-many Topics.

I can write a straight SQL query that gives me the results I want like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.ACTIVITY_VERSION av
WHERE ACTIVITY_VERSION_ID IN (
    SELECT ACTIVITY_VERSION_ID
    FROM dbo.ACTIVITY_TOPIC at
    WHERE at.TOPIC_ID IN (3,4)
)
```

What I can't figure out is how to write a LINQ query (we are using Linq to Sql) that returns the same results.

I've tried:

```
activities.Where(x => criteria.TopicIds.Intersect(x.TopicIds).Any());
```

this works if activities is a list of in memory objects (i.e. a Linq to Objects query), but I get an error if I try to use the same code in a query that hits the database. The error I receive is:

```
Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator.
```

I believe that this means that Linq to Sql doesn't know how to translate either Intersect or Any (or possibly both). If that is the case, I understand why it isn't working, but I still don't know how to make it do what I want it to and my Google-fu has not provided me with anything that works.

Comment: It's not the `Any` it's complaining about. It's complaining about `Intersect`.  You can only use `Contains` inside of your lambda when it involves a local sequence. (That's what the error message is saying).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tested it. But this is how you ll go about it.

```
List<int> IDs = new List<int>();
IDs.Add(3);
IDs.Add(4);

var ACTIVITY_VERSION_IDs = ACTIVITY_TOPIC
      .Where(AT => IDs.Contains(AT.TOPIC_ID))
      .Select(AT=>AT.ACTIVITY_VERSION_ID)

var results = ACTIVITY_VERSION
      .Where(AV => ACTIVITY_VERSION_IDs.Contains(AV.ACTIVITY_VERSION_ID))
```